# MySql server not recognizing correct password

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

I have installed MySql server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have prior experience to it too.

But whenever I login, using `mysql -u root -p` and after entering password it says:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have entered the correct password.
Same thing happened days back, but then I completely removed mysql and reinstalled it again.

Also I tried restarting the mysql server but no help!

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi, You can better reset the MySQL password by stopping the MySQL service first and start its services in safe mode. After that you can reset the MySQL password and then try login to MySQL with that password.

Comment: 2 thing: user "root". Are you sure about that? It is not your normal user name? And mind the caps-lock.

Comment: @rinzwind if not root then what? Because while installing it asked password for root, right?

Comment: @vembutech: helped and resolved.

Comment: We are glad to know the issue has resolved. Happy New Year !

Comment: It is good to tell how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always read the contents of `/usr/share/doc/`*package-name*`/` for packages you have installed.  They contain important information for using and administrating packages.

So for `mysql-server-5.5` there are important information in `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian.gz`. As it is `gzip`ped, it is convenient to use `zmore` to read it.

There you can see that you can use the `debian-sys-maint` user to access the database for administration.  Just as `root` use `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` configuration file to login as that user.  Notice that you **NEVER** should change that users password, unless you also change it in the file `debian.cnf`.  If not, mysql will stop working.

So, to change password for the `root` user, try this.

```
$ sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('*secret*') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit;
$ mysql -u root -p
```

If you can use the `*secret*` password to login in as user `root`, you have managed to change the password for `root`.

> Notice this use of the `debian-sys-maint` user only works for Debian based distributions.
>
> Notice also that if you also have the package `dbconfig-common` installed and set to store the `root` password (see `/etc/dbconfig/config`), you need to reconfigure that package so it knows the password to administrat your databases for other packages.

Lastly, good information can also be read in [Debians Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/) and in the free [The System administrators Book](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/)

Comment: Don't mind. I don't know much, but are there any security issues with this?

Comment: @Anders I have had to reset a few mysql root passwords in my time and have always used the method I posted, since that's what I found with a search. I have never had any problems, but your answer is definitely the correct one.

Comment: @SameerThigale, no that I know of that you wouldn't get anyway if  someone get their hands on the root account. Because if you get you computer hacked that much, you do have larger problems than someone hacking your MySQL installation. See the other solution which uses the computers root account.

Comment: @geoffmcc, any solution that works is right, but with this one you don't need to stop the MySQL server which could bee an advantage. And it is "The Debian Way™". ☺

Answer (score 3):

First stop the mysql server

```
 sudo service mysql stop
```

Run the following command that will start the server again and skip the grant tables which store the passwords.

```
 mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Mysql server should now start. Next we log into root without a password.

```
 mysql -u root
```

And then press enter

Now we run the following commands in mysql to reset the password

```
 update user set 
 Password=PASSWORD('new-password')
 where user='root';
 flush privileges;
 exit;
```

Now restart the mysql server

```
 sudo service mysql restart
```

You should now be able to log in with the password you just set

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

Press enter and you should get a prompt for root password and it should be accepted.

Comment: Is this a safe method?

Comment: Yes. Only option I really know of. All your doing in starting mysql without user passwords and then manually setting a new password

Comment: The only "problem" is that you for a short time rum without passwords on the MySQL server. And that you need to stop the server twice.

Comment: The MySQL docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic) also suggest running the server with --skip-networking.

Comment: Just a tip: in Debian before update I must select database: select database mysql;

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I solved it for me by adding `sudo`, e.g. `sudo mysql -u root -p` and using the password set at installation.

Comment: I've been working on this for hours; none of the guides I saw for installing mysql and running mysql_secure_installation mentioned this. And mysql_secure_installation didn't mention it. And FYI, I'm a longtime Ubuntu (and varients) user who instinctively things to throw sudo in front of a command that isn't working and I hadn't thought of it. Thank you, thank you.