# Uninstalling and reinstall MySQL for LAMP server (forgot password)

Tags: mysql, lamp

I have forgotten username and password for MySQL in LAMP stack on Ubuntu. I want to uninstall and reinstall MySQL for the LAMP server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover mysql password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679556/how-to-recover-mysql-password)

Comment: or maybe better this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/118772/how-to-change-root-password-for-mysql-and-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a file (i.e. mysql-reset) containing this line:

   ```sql
   SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
   ```
2. Run MySQL like:

   ```bsh
   $ mysqld_safe --init-file=/path/to/mysql-reset &
   ```

or

```bsh
$ mysqld -uroot --skip-grant-tables
```